# Emulate R in sagetex

Tags: sagetex

What is the most direct way to include R code in Sagetex? I tried `%r`, which does not work. (I do not want to use both Sweave and Sagetex.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%r` is a construct that only works in the Sage notebook or SageMathCloud. I suspect that the best thing here really is to use Sweave and SageTeX. You might be able to awkwardly get by with just SageTeX using Sage's R interface: for example,

```
sage: r.summary(r.c(1,2,3,111,2,3,2,3,2,5,4))
  Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.
  1.00    2.00    3.00   12.55    3.50  111.00
```

Doing `r.foo(...)` calls R's command `foo` (if it has been hooked into Sage). Here are some other things you can do:

```
sage: r.sd([1,2,3,4,100])
[1] 43.61766
sage: r.qnorm(.7123)
[1] 0.5601165
```

You might be able to typeset such things with the `sagecommandline` environment.

Comment: Maybe knitr would be another thing to use in this event.